# Pros and cons of having testable classes in header files instead of .cpp files when using gtest?

Tags: c++, gcc, googletest

I'm taking over a project with gigantic gtest suite. I'm adding extra tests. The way it was setup before me is the following. All testable classes are in header files and are included in main.cpp(test suite runner). 
Problem is, that compiler runs out of memory while trying to compile main.cpp with a lot of included files. The "normal" way of doing it is to have test classes in separate files, since gtest finds test classes through macro expansion. Figured that gtest has some sort of singleton with subscribers going.   **Can someone explain to me why would previous maintainer had test classes in header files? Pros and Cons** See a code example of having test classes in header files. 
    // file ZondTest.hpp

```
class ZondTest : public ::testing::Test

{
public:
   static const std::string INPUT_FILES_DIR;
protected:
   virtual void SetUp() //runs this set up before every test
   {
      //might put something here later if I need to

   }
};
const std::string ZondTest::INPUT_FILES_DIR =
                     "InputFiles/ZondManagerTest/";

class TestableZond_c : public Zond_c
{
public :

   TestableZond_c()
   {
   }

   virtual ~TestableZond_c()
   {
   }
};

//check if newly created zond has empty space
TEST(ZondTest,
       WhenCreatedNewZondWithoutSpaceExpectEmptySpace)
{
   TestableZond_c mTestableZond = TestableZond_c();
   EXPECT_TRUE(mTestableZond.SpaceEmpty());
}
// a tone more tests
// ....
```

included in main.cpp.

```
#include "RD/ZM/ZondTest.hpp"
//many more includes
//........
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Can you go a bit more into detail what you are doing, what you want to do and what is going wrong? You wrote some kind of `...Test.hpp` which you included in the `main.cpp`? Of the test project? And if so, why? The framework should find your test classes automatically. As you can tell, I have a very hard time following your question - and I fear I may not be the only one.

Comment: @CharonX I added some code samples to make people happy, but the question is not really about the code itself.

Comment: *deep breath* You don't add code samples to make people happy. You add code samples to make it easier (or even possible) for other people to help you. This is not paid tech support, **nobody here has any obligation to help you**, so try to make it as easy as possible for people who want to help. FFS.

Comment: So, again the question, why are you including all those test hpp files in your main? While I put my tests in .cpp files instead of .hpp files, they do not seem to need to be included in the main.cpp in order to be found and executed.

Comment: @CharonX keep breathing mate. I'm including test.hpp files in my main because it is how it was done before me. I'm taking over a project. And we arrived at a question. Why would people before me do it this way? I have no way of contacting whoever wrote this. And nobody here knows why is it the way it is. So I'm asking on SO. That's all. Nevertheless, I do agree that my wording and explanation could have been better formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that I figured out is that if you are using Eclipse, indexer cannot find a way to tie files that googletest automatically finds. So your file looks messy with all squiggly  underlines. But if you put TEST_P/TEST_F into header files and have them included in main. Eclipse indexer can "crawl" included files and build indexes and it looks pretty and gives false idea that it is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

I am uncertain what benefit placing the test cases in .hpp files instead of .cpp files (i.e. putting the `FnordTest` class in `FnordTest.hpp` instead of `FnordTest.cpp`) should bring...

The compiler (usually) does not create object files for headers thus making the inclusion of all those `.hpp` files in your main.cpp necessary, which may result in a single oversized compilation unit, causing your compiler to - as you said - run out of memory (especially when taking googletest's macro magic into account).

I can only recommend putting the tests into `.cpp` files - this way you do not even need to include them; googletest automagically finds all test you declare with TEST_P/TEST_F etc.